# Python simple network scanner for open port

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple port scanner in python without the use of nmap.

The below code is what  have so far:

```
    import socket,sys,optparse,netaddr


#INPUT
parser = optparse.OptionParser("usage: untitled1.py " "--ip <Network you want to scan, including mask in CIDR format> -P <target port>")
parser.add_option('--ip', dest='ip', type='string',  help='specify network to scan including /mask e.g 192.168.0.1/24')
parser.add_option('-P', dest='port', type='int',  help='specify target port')
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
port = str(options.port)
ip = str(options.ip)


if (ip == None) | (port == None):
    print parser.usage
    print 'You must specify a target network,including subnet mask and port.'
    exit(0)

#CREATE A SOCKET
try:
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error,err_msg:
  print 'Socket creation failed. Error code: '+ str(err_msg[0]) + ' Error mesage: ' + err_msg[1]
  sys.exit()

#PORT SCAN
targetlist = netaddr.IPNetwork(ip)
targetlist = list(targetlist)


for x in range (int(len(targetlist))):
    target_ip = targetlist[x]
    try:
      s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      s.settimeout(2)
      result = s.connect(str(target_ip), int(port))
      if not result :
        print str(target_ip) + ' Port '+  str(port) + ' open!'
      s.close()
    except:
      print str(target_ip)+' Port '+ str(port) + ' closed!'


s.close()
print "Scanning finished"
```

It does not seem to work as i am getting a port closed for every single IP or network I try to scan even though I am sure the particular port is open..

Most probably my mistake is in the way port scanning is defined but I cannot seem to put my finger on it.

I am at a beginner level so any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please make a [mcve], in other words, check your code works for one known ip &  port. Make that a method. Worry about the loops after that works